# Using Nokia Lumia 640 XL in 2019

Tags: unsupported-phones

As Lumia support line ended, **is it sane to keep using it for long?**
If I don't use anything except making basic phone call, sending text message, listen to music, watching videos offline, and taking few captures of library book pages etc?

I am thinking about disabling everything (even uninstall safely if that is possible) except those I want? I know browser would be useless in this fast moving modern web technology, and SSL will be a thing too....

I never use any web applications except browsers. My Lumia 640 XL battery still lasts like 4-5 days after a charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly it is as safe as the user using it. So if you are certain you don't open unrecognized links/email attachments etc, than you can use even a very 'unsafe' phone. Also there is nothing like a 'guaranteed safe' condition, not even on the newest phones.

If you want to be 'more' safe, restrict (or don't do) internet activities, and opening email or other 'external sources' links/attachments/files.

Comment: Cool. Really helpful :)